# Why do my lights glow when the switch is off?

Tags: electrical

I have 4 down lights controlled by 1 dimmer switch. When I turn them off they all still glow very slightly.

What causes this and how can I fix it?

Comment: Plenty of similar questions - take a look at: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/133558/led-lamp-keeps-glowing-when-dimmer-is-turned-off?rq=1 and https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/164250/led-downlights-glow-when-switched-off

Comment: What make and model is the dimmer, and what make and model are the downlights?